# Is animal agriculture the leading cause of species extinction?

Tags: environment, agriculture, extinction-event, sustainability

The cause of species extinction interests me.

*Cowspiracy: The Sustainability Secret* is a documentary that attacks the environmental damage caused by animal agriculture.

Their [facts](http://www.cowspiracy.com/facts/) page states (with references):

> **Animal agriculture is the leading cause of species extinction**, ocean dead zones, water pollution, and habitat destruction.  [xix]  [iv]

The page also contains many statements that are outright misinterpretations (like the dead oceans by 2048, or 51% of all greenhouse emissions made by animal agriculture), and the references are beyond me, so I don't know if this is true.

Is animal agriculture the leading cause of species extinction, in the modern period?

Comment: Also note that the report cited is looking at just 6% of vertebrates.

Comment: We've had two answers deleted because they didn't address the claim. I've made an edit in an attempt to make the claim we are addressing clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. According to Princeton University, **Deforestation** is the leading cause of species extinction.

> Evidence to date suggests that **deforestation is currently,** and is
>   projected to continue to be, **the prime**  direct and indirect cause of
>   reported extirpations. For  example, it is predicted that up to 21% of
>   Southeast  Asian forest species will be lost by 2100 because of past 
>   and ongoing deforestation. Similar projections exist for  biotas in
>   other regions.[1]

Though "animal agriculture" isn't **the** leading cause, it may contribute to extinction of species if it amounts to **Overexploitation**.

> Overexploitation is also an important driver of extinctions among
>   vertebrates and tends to operate synergistically with other drivers
>   such as habitat loss.[1]

Definition of Overexploitation:

> Overexploitation means harvesting species from the wild at rates
>   faster than natural populations can recover. Overfishing and
>   overhunting are both types of overexploitation.[2]

---

[1] http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s5_8879.pdf

[2] http://www.shmoop.com/conservation-biology/threats-overexploitation.html

Comment: Another user challenged this question, arguing that animal agriculture is the main cause of deforestation, so, by transitivity... (To my mind, this is a critique of the meaningless of the claim.)

Comment: That last comment caused confusion - let's take it to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47723/discussion-on-answer-by-mohammad-sakib-arifin-is-animal-agriculture-the-leading) to resolve..